# Bash command-history stopped working

Tags: bash, command-history

For some reason there are no more new entries in my `bash_history` file and executing `history` doesn't return anything. The owner of the history file is correct and has read, write access. I've tried

```
set -o history
```

but it didn't help either.

Does anybody know what might have triggered this behavior and how to re-enable history from this point?

EDIT:: here are a few useful details

```
$ echo $HISTFILESIZE
-1
$ echo $HISTSIZE
-1
```

Comment: Is your filesystem full? Check `df -h` and `df -i`.

Comment: the `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` variables control how much history Bash stores

Comment: `ls -ld ~/.bash_history` please, added to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a lot of reasons why this might happen.

The very first thing that you could check is the following variables:

- `HISTFILESIZE`
- `HISTSIZE`
- `HISTFILE`

Then you can use the following to check if the history works:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ echo $HISTFILE # this command will print place where history should be stored
/home/vagrant/.bash_history
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ history -a # this command appends newest command to the history
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ tail -2 $HISTFILE
echo $HISTFILE
history -a
```

You might check if you have write permission to the file stored in `HISTFILE` variable.

Comment: Tried changing the ```HISTSIZE``` and ```HISTFILESIZE``` to a positive number, it worked. isn't ```-1``` supposed to store unlimited history?

Comment: @dshri that's what `man bash` says, yes

Comment: @dshri: are you in bash and on a recent system? or maybe on an old unix server with an old version of (bash?) ... this could explain that setting to -1 erased its content

Comment: this happened on an aws ec2 instance with Ubuntu